# Sharing ~/.stack with docker

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Our team is using Docker for building our Haskell app in it, and in order to optimize build times, we work towards sharing the `~/.stack` directory from OS with the one inside docker containers. Initial implementation was to just reuse the one from OS, but it turned out this doesn't work quite well, it fails with an error like this:

```
The GHC located at /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc failed to compile a sanity check. Please see:
    http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/
for more information. Exception was:                                                                                                                                                 Running /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc /tmp/stack-sanity-check48/Main.hs -no-user-package-db in directory /tmp/stack-sanity-check48/ exited with ExitFailure 127

/root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc: line 9: /home/ubuntu/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/lib/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc: No such file or directory
make: *** [adserver_executables] Error 1
```

It seems like somewhere in `~/.stack` there is a cache which states an absolute path to GHC, and when we mount `~/.stack` in docker, it gets mounted as `/root/.stack` instead of `/home/<user>/.stack`, thus compiler can't be found by that path.

Our current decision is to make a separate directory `~/.docker-stack`, which we will use for all the docker-based builds, without interfering with the OS-level one. This is not ideal since it will use more space and will bring a need to re-compile packages even when they were compiled in non-docker OS-level environment.

Is there a better approach someone can propose to share `~/.stack` with inner-docker stack? Thank you.

Comment: Are you manually starting your Docker containers, as opposed to using Stack's built-in Docker support? The latter handles properly separating out host compilers and packages vs the container versions.

Comment: why are you mounting .stack in the firat place? docker could have its own .stack or a data only container that contains .stack

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman please see answer from our devops engineer https://gist.github.com/k-bx/695578ed7437a1fa37cc1cca722fb145

Comment: @madnight we create new staging env for every developer's branch/PR, building from scratch takes hours, so we need to have some nice caching

Comment: If the goal is to control the Docker images yourselves and reduce build time, I'd recommend building the necessary dependencies within a Docker image, and then (as @madnight mentions) mounting a Docker-specific directory for caching additional work. Such an approach is available at: https://github.com/fpco/stack-docker-image-build

Comment: i can confirm @MichaelSnoyman i think you are heading into the wrong direction with mounting ~/.stack from host